# XML file won't read data from one column in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, css, xml

I'm running a map-based application (Google Maps) from a MySQL database, using php and xml (the data is formatted into xml with php, then that xml file is pulled into a javascript function that ties individual data sets to markers on the map, per the Google API).

This was all working fine, until I made a change in the CSS.  Now, the data for one field is missing in the XML format.  The column name is still there, but no data.  Yet, the data is still in the database.  It may or may not be useful to know that this is the data that creates custom markers on the map (the sting feeds into a variable called "type" that is used to determine what color the marker will be).

I've tried deleting that column and replacing it, and have saved and uploaded the database numerous times.  Also made sure to keep clearing my browser's cache.  Nada.

Any ideas about why this might be happening?  Could it possibly be related to the CSS changes?  How?  And why would the data from only one column be affected?

Comment: I can't see any file, unfortunately. However, I don't see how any CSS change might destroy data. Anything is possible, but if it were me, I'd forget about CSS for now and focus on other things that changed around the same time. In fact, all of the things you mention is where I wouldn't look. The problem is probably in the PHP code that generates your XML data.